# ActiveRecord with mvc3

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-activerecord

I have an application built in MVC3 in C#.

Use ActiveRecord 3.0 and NHibernate 3.1 without problems, but I needed to improve the performance and I put in the relationships `[HasMany(Lazy=true)]` the attribute `Lazy=True`, for not reading the related registrations, but he is always bringing all of the registrations.

Does anybody have some idea of the one what can be?

Comment: when you access the collection it is loaded. can you show us the code where you see that its bringing all realted entities?

Comment: Hi Anton! Thanks for response.         
It follows the definition of the class, and soon afterwards the code that I use to access
[HasMany(typeof(ProtocoloAtividade), ColumnKey = "IdCliente", Table = "ProtocoloAtividade", Lazy = true)]
        public virtual IList<ProtocoloAtividade> ProtocoloAtividades
        {
            get
            {
                return this._protocoloAtividades;
            }
            set
            {
                this._protocoloAtividades = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Hi Firo!
He doesn't have code. I Put a break point in the line where is carried customer's registration that has a relationship with services. When I inspect the object Customer, I see all of the registrations of linked Services the Customer, and in the definition of the relationship this Lazy, therefore he should not bring the registrations!

Comment: Hi!
I isolated the problem. He happens when I use "using (new SessionScope ()) ". When I remove the command, it starts to work.     
Can anybody give me a light?    
    
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem, was not a problem, but a characteristic of Nhibernate and ActiveRecord in enviroment medium trust.

It was worth!